# used Sending funds address to receive bitcoins

Tags: address, sendtoaddress

Is there any way to get bitcoins when i accidentally used Bitcoin Core's "send to address" to get them?

Blockchain.info shows that there is balance, but the client shows 0 BTC and `dumpprivkey` does not work either.

Comment: "send to address" sounds like the section for sending payments of Bitcoin Core. It is not clear to me how you'd be able to "get bitcoins" with "send to address". If you've sent the bitcoins to a previous business partner (that was listed in the outgoing payments) you should know who that was, right? Have you tried contacting them? Did you perhaps send them to your deposit address on an exchange?

Answer (score 2):

If `dumpprivkey` provides no private key, then your wallet does not have it. You are not the owner of that address, and those bitcoins are not yours.